# Typing faster in the TextBox control in WP8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 application I am using a search method that search when the text in the TexBox is changing. Now i need to modify this search. When the user types fast in the TextBox the search should execute only after the user's typing. That is search method should not execute for each text changed. Is it possible? Plese help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Absolutely. You basically need a timer - or rather, a timer for each keystroke.

The simplest way of doing this is probably to say:

- Each time the user hits a key, start a timer. The timer should remember the text which was already typed at this time.
- When the timer fires, perform your search *if* the current text is the same as the "text at the point of timer start".

One *potential* downside of this is that if the user types "foo", the timer starts, the user types "d" and then deletes that "d", followed by the timer firing, it will execute the search despite the post-typing activity. *If* you decide that's undesirable, you can simply maintain a counter instead - just an `int` saying how many keystrokes there have been. Remember *that* when the timer starts, and check when the timer fires whether the count is the same as it was.

Alternatively, assuming the search is asynchronous and cheap, start a search on *every* keystroke... but when you get the results back, either ignore the search completely if the user has typed since then, or filter down the results locally to the ones which are still valid with the new query text.

(It's possible to do approach the problem with a *single* timer instead, such that when the user types *either* the timer is started *or* its firing time is delayed. Personally I think I'd find that more complicated, but it's up to you.)

Comment: Even if search is asynchronous and cheap they shouldn't run it on every keystroke just to throw results away. The end result is the same as with the timer method (i.e. results are only displayed for the text last entered) but we're on a mobile device here so should be a little conscious of unnecessary work, network traffic and the like.

Comment: @Joey: No, the end result isn't the same - the results are displayed quicker in the "always execute" approach. The latency from typing to results is "search time" rather than "timer + search time". It's important to balance the various trade-offs. For example, on wifi you may decide to take the faster approach, but use the more bandwidth-efficient approach on a cell network.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using [Reactive extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) library which is asynchronous way of communication and gives a lot of abstraction over asynchronous activities. It is a push based mechanism i.e. whenever data is available interested subscribers will be notified. It supports cancellation of issues requests etc.  And for examples please see the [101 Rx](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc25)